# Unable to add multiple groups to mailings

Tags: civimail, groups

Recently, when using CiviMail, I have been unable to include or add more than one group for the mailing recipient or exclude fields. It only allows me to select one group, and if I try and add another it replaces the existing one. This is affecting both the mosaico mailing and traditional mailing. It is not affecting selecting multiple groups on other screens apart from the two mailing screens.

When copying existing mailings, the recipients field now always says "undefined", though it still shows the correct number of recipients in red next to the recipient selection field.

I am running CiviCRM 5.64.3 with Drupal 9.5.10.

I have tried disabling all the extensions and this has made no difference. I have also tried re-installing from my composer.json file. This worked for a few days, and then stopped working again. There are also no errors showing in the Chrome console log.

I think the issue may have developed when I upgraded from 5.61 to 5.64, but I'm not sure. There are also no errors coming up in the Drupal log or the Civi log or the php error log.

[image]

Comment: Probably not, but possibly related to this issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4507, where the fix was to run composer civicrm:publish

Comment: That worked!! Yay! civicrm:publish really is magic. Almost as good as drush cr. If you want to add it as an answer I will confirm. Thank you so much! I spent about 2 days on this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related to this issue: [lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4507](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4507), where the fix was to run `composer civicrm:publish`